# Trouble with new install of OrientDB 2.1.9 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, orientdb

I am installing OrientDB 2.1.9 on Amazon Linux I am trying to log in to their standard Grateful Dead database. I cannot using the guest, the root works but this is non-optimal.

I used the default guest/guest, right out of the package.

The server credentials in the $ORIENTDB_HOME/config/orientdb-server-config.xml file:

Comment: Also I  can not add additional users either that can log in either.  <user> snippet from orientdb-server-config.xml <users>
        <user resources="*" password="sdfoijlk" name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="wichita" name="jackstraw"/>
    </users>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**guest** user is valid just to connect to server instance and list databases, to connect to the db you have to use db users or **root**

```
orientdb> connect remote:localhost guest guest

Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:localhost] with user 'guest'...OK


orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> connect remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts guest guest

Disconnecting from remote server [remote:localhost/]...
OK
Connecting to database [remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts] with user 'guest'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityAccessException: User or password not valid for database: 'GratefulDeadConcerts'
```

if you want to connect to the db with limited permissions you can use built-in users **reader** or **writer** or you can create your custom users from inside the database.

Please refer to this guide too http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Security.html

Comment: I'm going to say yes this does answer the question as I can connect using the console and I assume (maybe a bad idea) programmatically,  however I can not connect to the database view the browser; how is that different? Thanks

Comment: using the browser you connect directly to the database so you can use only db users and, of course, root